# How to get the TextInput value in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this code where I'm getting a user input. But when I'm console logging it to check it I'm getting an `object of type undefined`. I'm providing my code here. Please correct my code so that this bug is fixed.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoal, setGoal] = useState('');
  const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
    setGoal(enteredText);
  };
  const addGoalHandler = () => {
    console.log(enteredGoal);
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.inputTextContainer}>
        <TextInput
        style={styles.TextInput}
          placeholder="Course Goal"
          onChange={goalInputHandler}
          value={enteredGoal}
        />
        <Button title="ADD"  onPress={addGoalHandler} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the onChangeText prop

```
onChangeText={(text)=>goalInputHandler(text)}
```

This will pass the current text to goalInputHandler function

Comment: Can I directly pass it to setGoal

Comment: its still same object of type undefined

Comment: you can check this snack https://snack.expo.io/SkuCYNkYd if you need :)
you are welcome